# How to show tooltip data below each column in Highchart?

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, column-chart

The tooltip data in highchart is visible when i hover my mouse over it, the tooltip has some data that i want to show for example below the column where the x label is, for now it shows 0,1,2 and so on.

I am using the chart to compare timeperiods, so under each column i want to add data from the tooltip. It could be 2 dates I compare below each column, a picture would be helpful for you but i am not a trusted stackoverflow user yet.

Comment: You can do this by using **categories** on your x axis, or by using a **datetime** x axis type. Refer to the demos and the docs: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/ | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: Yes I klnow that, but i compare sometimes 2 different dates and i want to show both of them below the column.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific then. To clarify, the data has nothing to do with the tool tip - the data in the tool tip is point/series data. You can use the axis label **formatter** function to pull in any number of data elements, but how exactly to do it depends on what you have and what you want.  Set up a fiddle so we can get more specific.  | Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: As an addition to jlbriggs posts, you can add custom labels below your xAxis categories using chart.renderer.label or chart.renderer.text, you can find an example of using this methods in Highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.label But I think that the best is to use label formatter (if I understand your problem correctly)

Comment: Here is an example fiddle. In the tooltip you see the name of the serie and the date. I want to show the date below each series in the columns. http://jsfiddle.net/46djperk/9/

Comment: This is what you would like to achieve? I have used labels.formatter as I have mentioned before. http://jsfiddle.net/46djperk/11/

Comment: But again - if you want the data associated with a point, you should really use a datetime axis. I know this is just an example, but it doesn't make much sense as it is - you have two points, each in a different series, and then two dates below them both - what are the two dates? Which point applies to which date...or...what's what, in general? This seems like a set up that is bound to cause confusion.

Comment: Thanks guys, a labels formatter is the way to go i think but i will also have a look at the datetime axis. My real chart shows a shop that compare different timeperiods, lets say every monday for month june and july. First monday of the two month will show in column 0 and second monday will show in column 1 and so on. Here i want the date labels below each column, like the fiddle you linked Grzegorz with some changes.

Comment: Unless I completely misunderstand what you're saying, you're literally describing a datetime axis, or a categorical axis (either would work, depending on more specific detail) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using a `datetime` `xAxis` `type`:

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/1bs6vL3t/

**Code:**

In the xAxis properties, specify the type as `datetime`:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime'
},
```

In the series, specify your x values as dates (using either the Date.UTC() method, or by directly specifing epoch time)

```
series: [{
  data: [
    [Date.UTC(2016, 05, 6), 3],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 05, 13), 5],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 05, 20), 4],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 05, 27), 7],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 06, 4), 6],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 06, 11), 9],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 06, 18), 7],
    [Date.UTC(2016, 06, 25), 5]
  ]
}]
```

**Output:**

[image: screenshot]

**And, an alternative version that uses categories instead:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/1bs6vL3t/2/

Generally, when working with time series data, using `datetime` is preferable. There may be cases where various circumstances make it less effective, in which case `categories` can be a useful alternative.

**{{ Edit }}**
After re-reading your comments, here's another version, using categories, that might be more like what you're looking for:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/1bs6vL3t/5/

[image: screenshot]

This may also be a case for the Grouped Categories plugin:

- http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. I will try send a picture of my chart insted of describing it tomorrow.

Comment: Yes thanks, i made it with categories. I am using angular and with some changes i made it worked. Thanks for all your help.