# How to display tooltip data below x-axis category labels using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display the tooltip values below my x-axis category labels using [Highcharts](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter) but won't work. I found below link but won't work.

> [How to show tooltip data below each column in Highchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850836/how-to-show-tooltip-data-below-each-column-in-highchart)

What I have right now is:

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['7789 - 70', '7877 - 12', '7876 - 12', '7876 - 7', '7877 - 7', '7876 - 20', '7876 - 28', '7875 - 12', '7876 - 129', '7877 - 129'],
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value+'<br>'+'{series.name}';
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gL89gvqf/2/)

Comment: can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, updated with fiddle

Comment: try return  this.chart.series[0].name ;

Comment: @Sajeetharan, thanks man. how about the corresponding values?

Comment: you can add a console.log() inside the formatter and take whatever you need

Comment: @Sajeetharan, yeah a bunch of data in console :) need to test them which is which :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack, but you can try, will try to find a better solution and post

```
xAxis: {
      categories: ['7789 - 70', '7877 - 12', '7876 - 12', '7876 - 7', '7877 - 7'],
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          console.log(this.chart.series);
          return this.chart.series[0].name;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah :) need to try these data

Comment: Tried this `this.chart.series[0].data[0].stackTotal` but no luck.

Comment: I updated my fiddle above. Try to check the tooltip. Can we get that kind of format below category labels?

Comment: you mean series and data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128115/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-claudios).

Comment: you got it sorted?

Comment: Nope :D I am doing the percentage now and til now not fixed. :) but I managed to display the data for each series below category thanks!